# C++: Create vector with sequence number in place

Tags: c++, vector, sequence

I need to create an `std::vector` / `std::initializer_list` with a sequence of numbers, and I was wondering whether is there an alternative to the following function (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8EjrYKhE6) that would create the vector without having a secondary vector filled up:

```cpp
std::vector<int> generate(int cnt)
{
    std::vector<int> result(cnt);
    std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), 0);
    return result;
}
```

(i.e., something else to create the vector with sequence already filled in, "in place" without the need to call a function - I am using this in a member initializer list, and it works perfectly, I am just curios if it can be shortened to something else).

Comment: A C++20 iota range as a constructor argument might work. Not an answer because I don't know enough about that.

Comment: If `cnt` is known at compile time, you could use `integer_sequence` with `vector(initializer_list)` to do that.

Comment: As an aside: There will be no secondary vector after compiling the code since the compiler will use RVO to move the vector from inside the function to the function call location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it through C++20's range adaptor [`std::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> generate(int cnt)
{
  auto r = std::views::iota(0, cnt);
  return {r.begin(), r.end()};
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/4578e6h6P)